# Automated domain registration

Tags: php, dns

I'm busy writing a app that automacally defines a domain on a server and defines the nameservers and registers a domain. At the moment it only registers .co.za domains which are really easy to register since you only fill in a form and send and the domain then gets registered, I do this this via a PHP script which fills in the form and then sends it. Now I need to do the same for .mobi sites, but this somehow is not possible to automate, since everywhere you first need to register on the website and login to register a domain name. Are there any methods I can use to have this automated as well, since the company I'm working for registers about 20domains per day, and I do not want to fill in all forms manually.

Comment: you should look for some API. doing it via browser emulation is certainly not preferred way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to make an account or contract with a company like [register.com](http://www.register.com/) or [dynadot](http://www.dynadot.com/domain/api.html), which allow to register domains for several countries.

Maybe there are domain provider (like [dynadot](http://www.dynadot.com/domain/api.html)) offering a API, or you can hack it with php the way you are used to. google with "[register domain api](http://www.google.com/search?q=register+domain+%2Bapi)"

Answer (score 1):

Look for registrars who provide reseller support, they typically have an API for bulk registrations.